# CAS Server Authentication Failure using Maven build and Ellucian Luminis LDAP

Tags: ldap, war, cas

I followed the instructions at (https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Best+Practice+-+Setting+Up+CAS+Locally+using+the+Maven2+WAR+Overlay+Method) for building the CAS server, and then the instructions for authenticating through LDAP (https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/LDAP).  However, I keep getting the following error message in my Tomcat logs:

**[LDAP: error code 34 - Invalid DN]; nested exception is javax.naming.InvalidNameException: [LDAP: error code 34 - Invalid DN]**

I have verified that my bind user credentials are correct as I am able to perform the following search from the command line:
**ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://fuller.edu:636 -b "ou=People,o=fuller.edu,o=cp" -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w "password" "(sn=Smith)" cn sn pdsLoginId**
The results from that search are correct and nearly instantaneous.

At this point, I'm not entirely certain what I'm missing.  Below are snippets from my deployerConfigContext.xml file.

```
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler"
                                    p:filter="pdsLoginId=%u"
                                    p:searchBase="ou=People,o=fuller.edu,o=cp"
                                    p:contextSource-ref="contextSource" />
<bean id="contextSource"
class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
       <property name="pooled" value="true"/>
        <property name="url" value="ldaps://fuller.edu:636" />
        <property name="userDn" value="cn=Directory Manager"/>
        <property name="password" value="our password"/>
        <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
              <map>
                    <entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout" value="3000" />
                    <entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout" value="3000" />
                    <entry key="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple" />
              </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I've searched through several posts here at stackoverflow.com, and tried most of the answers, but without luck.  I'm hoping someone will spot what is missing in my configuration and send me in the right direction.

I'm happy to post any more code that you may need to see.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command line LDAP bind test uses the DN of `"ou=People,o=our.edu,o=cp"` but the config file specifies the DN of `ou=People,o=edu,o=cp`.  Those are not the same.

`o=our.edu` or `o=edu`

**Comment explained, it is `ou=People,o=fuller.edu,o=cp`**

Next step would be to see if you need to escape the period with a backslash, so that `ou=People,o=fuller.edu,o=cp` which works on the command line, might beed to be `ou=People,o=fuller\.edu,o=cp` in the configuration file.

Comment: That was just the example I used for the question.  The Luminis server uses ou=People,o=shoolname.edu,o=cp.  I've modified the question so that it uses my domain name.  Just had a moment of paranoia about posting my ldap server config online when I asked the question yesterday.

Comment: You are fantastic!  I can't believe it was simply escaping the extra period.  But that did it.  Logged me in.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mike Glad to help, send fish.